# Using pandas to merge 2 dataframes that have a different number of rows

Tags: python, pandas, merge, rows

I am a total newbie at this and python, so forgive the basicness of question.

I am trying to merge 3 different dataframes that each have a different number of rows and I used these commands

```
x = pd.merge(activated_at_df, spend_df)
x
all_dfs = pd.merge(x, df_rep)
all_dfs
```

For example `activated_at_df` and `spend_df` have a different number of rows. `activated_at_df` has 150k rows and `spend_df` has 100k rows, so I would like all 150k rows to show up and have the columns that don't have information (the 50k rows that are not in the `spend_df`) blank.

They do all have unique identifiers, `id`

So I tried

```
x = pd.merge(activated_at_df, spend_df, on='id')
x
```

but that also didnt work

Would be very appreciative if anybody could help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to do:

```
x = pd.merge(activated_at_df, spend_df, how='outer', on='id')
```

Note the `how='outer'`, which does a full outer join. More on this in [the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#brief-primer-on-merge-methods-relational-algebra).

Answer (score 0):

The question could benefit from a little example. It sounds like you could use .concat():

```
all_dfs = pd.concat([activated_at_df, spend_df], axis=1)
```